# Basic MVC with linked tables

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0

I am new to cakephp.
I am working on an application where authors can create new and translate existing articles to their language. 
I have three tables: articles, article_translations and authors.

When an author creates a new article, a record in article and article_translations is created.
When an author translate an existing article, a record only in article_translations is created.

```
articles
------
id
authors_id
preview_image
detail_image
...

article_translations
------
id
article_id
authors_id
language
title
subtitle
...

authors
------
id
user_name
email
...
```

I baked models, controllers and templates, and they are working fine.

articles Model:

```
class RecipesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('articles');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'authors_id'
        ]);

        $this->hasMany('ArticleTranslations', [
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id'
        ]);

    }
// Some validation methods  
}
```

article_translations model

```
class ArticleTranslationsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('article_translations');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('Articles', [
            'foreignKey' => 'author_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
// Some validation methods  

}
```

authors model

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('authors');
        $this->setDisplayField('user_name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
    }
// Some validation methods  
}
```

Articles Controller

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Authors']
        ];
        $articles = $this->paginate($this->Articles);

        $this->set(compact('articles'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['articles']);
    }
    // More methods 
}
```

ArticleTranslations Controller

```
class ArticleTranslationsController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Articles']
        ];
        $articleTranslations = $this->paginate($this->ArticleTranslations);

        $this->set(compact('articleTranslations'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['articleTranslations']);
    }
    // More methods 
}
```

Authors Controller

```
class AuthorsController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $authors = $this->paginate($this->Authors);

        $this->set(compact('authors'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['authors']);
    }
    // More methods 
}
```

The Articles template (=index function) renders the following table:
    id    Author       preview_image
    --------------------------------
    1       
    2       
    ...........

What I want is a list of all article translations for all articles, like this:

```
<preview_image of article one>

id    Author       title             language
---------------------------------------------
1     <user_name>  <article_title>    en
1     <user_name>  <article_title>    fr


<preview_image of article two>

id    Author       title             language
---------------------------------------------
2     <user_name>  <article_title>    it
2     <user_name>  <article_title>    de

.
.
.
```

But how do I load data from article_translations in the Articles Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Articles Controller, just extend the containment to include the data you want.

```
'contain' => ['Authors', 'ArticleTranslations']
```